# Setup a Static IP Addressed Linux network oin Parallels

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, parallels, ansible

Our requirement is to have static IPS in our parallel machines for us not to change our SSH hosts for in Ansible.

In the Parallels, virtual machine settings are done for Linux.
I am using a **Host-Only** network for machines to do **SSH** to each other.

My machines
Web machine is 192.168.2.2

Load Balancer machine is 192.168.2.3

DB machine is 192.168.2.4

Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

Gateway: 192.168.2.1 ( where do we assign this to parallels preferences ? )

DNS : 8.8.8.8

These machines need to be able to access web resources to install packages and the controller machine should be able to access the other machines over SSH. They are all Linux boxes.

Set up the networking as Bridged (rather than NAT or Shared) as it was the way to connect with them for me to use SSH.

I can not access web resources after assigning static IP addresses to the machines.

Shared option shows an internet access which confuses me as the machines already connect to online resources if they use a DHCP.
Should I manipulate the default settings and assign 192.168.2.1-192.168.2.254 ?
[image]

Sample Assignment on the Host machine
[image]

Comment: so If I understand if you let the machine get it ip adresse from DHCP the mahcine can access the internet,   if you set it manually it doesn't?

Comment: Yes that confuses me.